# Correct word order in prepositional phrases of the type to be + verb + preposition

Tags: word-order, prepositional-phrases

which are correct word orders for prepositional phrases of the type

> to be + verb + preposition?

E.g., which of the following examples containing the phrase

> to be aware of

are correct?

> 1. ...the fact, *of which he was aware* ...
> 2. ...the fact, *which he was aware of*...
> 3. ...

Comment: Take your choice. They're both fine.

Comment: Is one of these preferable to the other, stylistically? Or is it just a matter of taste and variation?

Comment: Neither is preferable. Most people today would probably use the second. There is no rule about final prepositions although there was once such a convention in some stuffy circles.

Answer (score 0):

The rule states that clauses and sentences should not end with prepositions, but it is relaxing.

Sir Winston Churchill:

> This is the sort of English up with which I will not put.

https://www.gsbe.co.uk/grammar-prepositions.html

Both of your examples are fine.

Comment: Interesting quote. Although it follows the same pattern as my 2nd example, it sounds wrong and nobody would ever use it in a serious way.

Comment: It is in a similar form as your 1st example.